# From formal models to programs - Model Checking

Tags: reference-request, model-checking, formal-methods, program-verification, temporal-logic

I am reading on Automata, Model Checking and CTL/LTL. I am looking for examples/references/books that help me understand the following:

1. Given a program (for example Python or Java), how can I change various parts to automata / logical languages, to perform formal analysis / model checking?
2. Given an automata and a logical specification (which has been verified to be correct) how can I construct a program (for example Python or Java) that will also be correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for software that will help you do this, or for the theory of how one would carry this out?

Comment: @cody Pehaps first theory, and secondly, a software would be interesting too. But theory is what I am really looking for.